# Why are functions with vanishing normal derivative dense in smooth functions?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

**Question**

> Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with piecewise smooth boundary. Why are smooth functions with vanishing normal derivative dense in $C^\infty(M)$ in the $H^1$ norm?

Here I define $C^\infty(M)$ to be those functions which have all orders of derivative continuous on $M$ and smooth in its interior. For example, $(x\mapsto \sin(\pi x))\in C^\infty([0,1])$ but $(x\mapsto \sqrt{x})\notin C^\infty([0,1])$.

This is crossposted from [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463070/why-are-functions-with-vanishing-normal-derivative-dense-in-smooth-functions).

---

**Background**

This is inspired by my belief that the form domain of the Friedrichs extension of the Neumann Laplacian on $M$ is equal to $H^1(M)$. If my belief is wrong, I would certainly accept as answer a counterexample, preferably with some discussion/references.

Here are some approaches I'm exploring.

- Given $u\in C^\infty(M)$ construct a function that agrees away from an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $\partial M$, but has been modified to have zero normal derivative. This is described below, but runs into some trouble at corners and with smoothing.
- Given $u\in C^\infty(M)$, find some $\eta$ supported on an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $\partial M$ such that $\nabla\eta|_{\partial M}$ is equal to the projection of $\nabla u|_{\partial M}$ onto the normal direction and $\eta$ and $|\nabla\eta|$ uniformly bounded in $\epsilon$. Then $u - \eta$ will be the desired approximation and uniform boundedness will imply $\|u - (u-\eta)\|_{H^1}\to 0$. I'm not sure if this is a search for an integrable harmonic vector field or if it's a constrained optimization problem.
- Simply show that any $u\in C^\infty(M)$ that is perpendicular to all smooth functions with vanishing normal derivative must be zero. In order to do this, I think it still runs into the same fundamental difficulty as the others, which is constructing functions with vanishing normal derivative supported on an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the boundary.

I'm also happy to simply have a reference to follow up. A reference for domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ should be fine, too, and just a partition of unity away from a Riemannian manifold.

---

**Current Approach**

The approach I'm considering right now is an elaboration on possibility (2) from my list. The sketch is: set the boundary condition that $\nabla\eta$ on the boundary be equal to the normal component of $\nabla u$ and find an integrable harmonic vector field $E$ satisfying that boundary condition. Then cut off $E$ so it is only supported in a neighborhood of $\partial M$, and let $\eta$ be so that $E = \nabla\eta$.

Intuition is that the maximum principle will control $|E|$ and $|\eta|$, so that $\eta$ will be bounded above in the $H^1$ norm by a constant times the volume of the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\partial M$.

Another approach is inspired by zhw's comment on MSE: approximate $\nabla u$ among $L^2$ vector fields, multiply it by a cutoff function so it is supported in the interior of $M$, and then integrate it to approximate $u$. This should work with some tweaking in $[0,1]$ but I'm not sure how well it will work in general.